# How can I fix where the player circle moves with the w,a,s,d keys in the grid I created

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay, so my for my final project I'm creating a dungeon crawler and I have a grid set up where the player moves and thus far I'm working on getting the GUI finished before I link the rest of the files together with the attack function. Anyways my issue is that my player circle won't move in the grid I created, here is the code if you don't know what I mean:

gui.py

```
try:
    from tkinter import *

except ImportError as err:
    print('a', err)

from player import *

class SimpleGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Final Project')
        self.window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',self.exit)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window,
                             width = 245,
                             height = 550,
                             bg = 'white')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.player = Player()

        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.canvas.bind('w', self.w_key)
        self.canvas.bind('a', self.a_key)
        self.canvas.bind('s', self.s_key)
        self.canvas.bind('d', self.d_key)


        self.running = True
        self.menu = Menu

        self.bt1 = Button(self.window,
                         text = 'Start',
                         command = self.menu)
        self.bt1.pack()




        self.mainloop()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def mainloop(self):
        while self.running:
            self.canvas.delete(ALL)
            #boss square
            boss_start = self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,0,150,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #player start square
            ply_start = self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,500,150,550, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 9
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,50,50,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,50,150,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,50,200,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,50,250,100, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 8
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,100,50,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,100,100,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,100,150,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,100,200,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,100,250,150, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 7
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,150,50,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,150,100,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,150,150,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,150,200,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,150,250,200, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 6
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,200,50,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,200,100,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,200,150,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,200,200,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,200,250,250, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 5
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,250,50,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,250,100,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,250,150,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,250,200,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,250,250,300, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 4
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,300,50,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,300,100,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,300,150,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,300,200,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,300,250,350, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 3
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,350,50,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,350,100,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,350,150,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,350,200,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,350,250,400, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 2
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,400,50,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,400,100,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,400,150,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,400,200,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,400,250,450, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            #row 1
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,450,50,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(50,450,100,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,450,150,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(150,450,200,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,450,250,500, outline = 'black', fill = 'black', width = 2)
            self.player.draw(self.canvas)

            self.canvas.after(30)
            self.canvas.update()

    def button1(self):
        print('working')

    def a_key(self, event):
        self.player.x -= self.player.speed

    def w_key(self, event):
        self.player.y -= self.player.speed

    def s_key(self, event):
        self.player.y += self.player.speed

    def d_key(self, event):
        self.player.x += self.player.speed

    def exit(self):
        self.running = False
        self.window.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleGUI()
```

player.py

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, hp = 100, defense = 10, strength = 10):
        self.hp = hp
        self.defense = defense
        self.strength = strength
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.speed = 64

    def draw(self, canvas): 
        canvas.create_oval(self.x,self.y,self.x+45,self.y+45, fill='red') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = Player()
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to make the circle go completely inside the square, if you move it all the way to the right on the grid its off by a few pixels. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

This just isn't how to do animation in tkinter. You shouldn't be replacing the built-in `mainloop` with your own while loop.

To do animation, draw your board exactly once. Then, create a function to *update* the board. Finally, call this function with `after` periodically. This will allow your UI to be responsive while keeping the board up to date.

In otherwords, instead of this:

```
def mainloop():
    while self.running:
        ...
        self.canvas.after(30)
        self.canvas.update()
```

... you should do something like this:

```
def update_display():

    <update the display based on current information>

    if self.running:
        # update the screen again in 30 ms
        self.after(30, update_display)
```

For the "update the display" part, you can use the canvas `move` and/or `coords` methods to move the oval. There's no need to delete and completely redraw during every iteration -- just redraw the things that have changed. The same is true for the player -- draw it once, and then just move it from then on.

Your application will perform much better with this architecture.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem with this is. I copied your code and when I run your project the red circle moves appropriately with the wasd keys. Is lack of proper collision the issue?

Comment: The issue is that I need the circle to go exactly into the middle of the squares on the grid, simply edit the fill on the circles to change it from black to white and you will get a better idea of what I mean, also, I need to figure out a way to make sure the dot can only go inside the black squares and nothing else, is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @MylesTaft: have you tried simply using a little math to make sure the coordinates are aligned the way you want?